# foreach folder echo foreach image

Tags: php, html, foreach

I'm currently using this

```
foreach (glob('img/gallery/*') as $dir) {
    $folder = str_replace('img/gallery/', '', $dir);
    foreach (glob($dir.'/*.jpg') as $img)  {
        $img1 = str_replace('img/gallery/'.$folder.'/', '', $img);
        $img1 = str_replace('.jpg', '', $img1);
        $img = str_replace(' ', '%20', $img);?>
        <a class="portfolio" title="<?=$img1?>" href="<?=$img?>">
            <li class="mix <?=$folder?>" 
                data-cat="<?=$folder?>" 
                style="height:145px;width:145px;float:left;margin-right:2.5px;margin-left:2.5px;margin-bottom:5px; background:url(<?=$img?>);background-size:cover;">
            </li>
        </a>
    <? }
}
```

And it's working fine doing exactly what I need, getting all of the files and folder names and displaying them, the problem is now that i've got:

**Warning**:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in **index.php** on line **188**

Displaying in the source code, but it's all working. Line 188 is the second foreach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are there any files in your subdirs? e.g. `/img/gallery/somefile`, which you then try to glob again with `img/gallery/somefile/*.jpg`, which would fail the second glob, returning a boolean false and triggering your error message.

You need to check if what you're globbing internally is actually a dir, e.g.

```
foreach(glob(...) as $dir) {
    if (issdir($dir)) {
         ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Of course, as soon as I read your first question it clicked, one of the folders is empty so it's not returning any results!! It's been a long day!!

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$images = glob($dir.'/*.jpg');
if (count($images))
foreach($images as $img) {
```

Comment: Thanks for this, but now: <b>Warning</b>:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in <b>index.php</b> on line <b>191</b>

Comment: and now? i missed the $

Answer (score 1):

Use `GLOB_ONLYDIR`as flag in your first foreach to get only directories:

```
foreach (glob('img/gallery/*',GLOB_ONLYDIR) as $dir) {
```